# How to use previous commit state in git and not present on same file?

Tags: git, powershell, github, rm

I modified some project files(profilePage.js and profile.js) and then added them to commit, but I didn't push as I had a backup to delete. Then I accidentally deleted profile.js through powershell using 
rm profile.js

[image: Problem Image]

instead of the profile.js.backup
now I just want to remove uncommited version of file that got deleted and use only the file preserved in commit.
How to achieve this?
Adding to `.gitignore` didn't solve this.

Comment: Check your IDE to see if it can recover the changes?

Comment: Solved, just committed changes which were in green(added) and didn't add the changes in red, Recovered the pushed changes manually back in local. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Even if the file is no longer on disk, it is in the index.

That means this will restore the file:

```
git commit -m "commit changes"
git checkout -- profile.js
```